# Jquery: Highlight/De-highlight table row on click

Tags: jquery

I want my script to highlight the row that I select and it works great, but when a row is selected/highlighted i want it to be "deselected/dehighlighted" if another row is selected. How do i do this?

Here is current code for selecting a row, it deselects, but only if i click on the same row again:

```
$(".candidateNameTD").click(function() {
            $(this).parents("tr").toggleClass("diffColor", this.clicked);
        });
```

**Html table**

```
<table id="newCandidatesTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="cursor: pointer;">ID</th>
            <th style="cursor: pointer;">Navn</th>
            <th style="cursor: pointer;">Email</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <% foreach (var candidate in Model.Ansogninger)
    {
         %>
            <tr id="<%= candidate.AnsogerID %>" class="newCandidatesTableTr">
                <td><div id="candidateID"><%= candidate.AnsogerID %></div></td>
                <td><div id="<%= "candidateName_" + candidate.AnsogerID %>" class="candidateNameTD"><%= candidate.Navn %></div></td>
                <td><div id="candidateEmail"><%= candidate.Email %></div></td>
                <td>
                    <div id="<%= "acceptCandidateButton_" + candidate.AnsogerID %>" class="acceptb" style="cursor: pointer; border: 1px solid black; width: 150px; text-align: center;">Godkend</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
         <%
    } %>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could first deselect all rows, like

```
    $(".candidateNameTD").click(function() {
        $(this).closest("tr").siblings().removeClass("diffColor");
        $(this).parents("tr").toggleClass("diffColor", this.clicked);
    });
```

edit: yep, sry, but the idea was right ;)

Comment: This will only deselect the clicked row.

Comment: thanks, i used your idea... it was the most logical for me :)

Comment: btw if you have nested tables this will match all tr's. closest is better

Answer (score 6):

```
$(".candidateNameTD").click(function() {
            $("tr").removeClass("diffColor");
            $(this).parents("tr").addClass("diffColor");
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

This will only affect the current table:

```
$(".candidateNameTD").click(function() {
    $('table#newCandidatesTable tr').removeClass("diffColor");
    $(this).parents("tr").addClass("diffColor");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Best using `.live`. One event is preferred over many (think big table, big overhead).

```
$("div.candidateNameTD").live('click'. function() {
    var $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
    //remove any selected siblings 
    $tr.siblings().removeClass('diffColor');
    //toggle current row
    $tr.toggleClass('diffColor');         
});
```

Comment: @redsquare - not necessary unless he's dynamically appending/injecting rows.