# Get the Previous clicked tag using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jquery: Highlight/De-highlight table row on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287699/jquery-highlight-de-highlight-table-row-on-click)

I created a html table that contain several TR tags. now I want, when a user click on a row in the table then it becomes highlighted and the previous clicked become un-highlighted.
Can anybody tell how can I do it. I am trying to do it using jquery.

Comment: You can store that somewhere, or unhiglight all rows.

Comment: Use: `$("tr").click(function() { $("tr").removeClass("highlighted"); $(this).addClass("highlighted"); });`

Comment: thanx dbaseman also there is one more problem in it. i have added a server side control inside table row and when i clicked that control it highlights the row and as soon as the page post back it is unhiglighted. what i need to do to make it highlighted even after postback the web page.

Comment: @user1262790 Making a highlight survive browser navigation is unrelated to this. Look up `LocalStorage`, `SessionStorage` or send the data through server.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
// on click of any of the table cell...
$("td").click(function() {

    // Remove the active class from all the tr's
    $(this).closest("tr").siblings().removeClass("active");

    // Add the active class to the clicked table row...
    $(this).parents("tr").toggleClass("active", this.clicked);
});
```

*CSS*

Nothing much to see here, just that we will have a class name ready to handle the actual styling of "current" rows and columns.

```
.active { background-color: #eee; }
```

[**Fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/MaRyz/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution. It adds/removes the class `hilite` to the latest clicked `<tr>`.

```
$( 'tr' ).on( 'click', function() {
    var classname = 'hilite';
    $( 'tr.' + classname ).add( this ).toggleClass( classname );
} );
```

You can test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/GvXKe/